# How to create a test for a custom ParameterResolver implementation?

Tags: java, junit5-extension-model

I've created a ParameterResolver implementation in order to inject a parameter into my test methods.
I have a scenario where the instantiation of the parameter object could fail without some proper parameters defined by the correspondent annotation and an exception is thrown.

```
  @TestScenario(homeDirName = "")
  @Test
  void ensureFailingWithoutProperHomeDirectory(LauncherRuntime launcher) {

    assertThrows(MissingPropertiesException.class,
                 () -> launcher.run());
  }
```

But this test is failing even before starting to run, with a ParameterResolutionException.

I would like to know how can I test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to test your ParameterResolver implementation and not the JUnit engine the entry point of your Unit test should be the `provideArguments` method of your implementation. JUnit catches every exception that is thrown by this method and adds it as cause for a new ParameterResolutionException. There are two possible approaches:

**A)**
If your implementation should call multiple methods of `ExtensionContext` then mock these methods together with your annotation. And call the `provideArguments` of your implementation.

**B)**
If your implementation should use the `ExtensionContext` only to get the annotation and does nothing more with it that is worth for testing, then move main functionality into an own method (e.g. `accept(MyAnnotation)`) and test this method. See for example [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/3f7fed61f2edcee2a5551dbde75382b1dbe21267/junit-jupiter-params/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvArgumentsProviderTests.java) how the JUnit developers to this for the CVSSource annotation.

Here's an example test case for my `ResourceFilesArgumentsProvider` / `ResourceFilesSource` annotation:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

class ResourceFilesArgumentsProviderTest {

  @Test
  public void nonExistingDirectory() throws Exception {

    ResourceFilesSource annotation = resourceFiles("/non-existing-dir");

    AnnotatedElement annotatedElement = mock(AnnotatedElement.class);

    when(annotatedElement.getAnnotation(ResourceFilesSource.class))
      .thenReturn(annotation);

    ExtensionContext context = mock(ExtensionContext.class);
    when(context.getElement()).thenReturn(Optional.of(annotatedElement));
    when(context.getTestClass()).thenReturn(Optional.of(getClass()));

    assertThrows(NoSuchFileException.class, () -> provideArguments(context));
  }

  private Stream<Object[]> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    ResourceFilesArgumentsProvider provider = new ResourceFilesArgumentsProvider();
    return provider.provideArguments(context).map(Arguments::get);
  }

  private ResourceFilesSource resourceFiles(String directory) {

    /* mock the annotation with Mockito, or alternatively create
     * an anonymous class with new ResourceFileSource() { ... }
     */
    ResourceFilesSource annotation = mock(ResourceFilesSource.class);
    when(annotation.directory()).thenReturn(directory);
    return annotation;
  }

}
```